# How to emit / catch events from constructor in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, events, constructor

There are already a lot of questions, how to emit event from constructor in nodejs. Most number of this issues - event is fired before listener is added:

```
var fooBar = new FooBar() // event is emitted
fooBar.on('event', function(){}); // never will be executed
```

There is a workaround: to fire event in constructor only after `newListener` [event is fired](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_event_newlistener). In this case, only one listener can be added. Is this normal practice to do that?

I see that readline in fact provides same interface:

```
var io = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  terminal: false
});

io.on('line', function(line) {}); // listener is added after constructor
```

Does it work using `newListener` event?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's another workaround, using [`setImmediate`](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_setimmediate_callback_arg):

```
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
var inherits     = require('util').inherits;

function FooBar() {
  var instance = this;
  EventEmitter.call(instance);
  setImmediate(function() {
    instance.emit('event', 'hello world');
  });
}

inherits(FooBar, EventEmitter);

var fooBar = new FooBar();
fooBar.on('event', function(value) {
  console.log('got event:', value);
});
```

This makes emitting the event asynchronous, which means that it will be scheduled until after any synchronous code (like calling the constructor and adding the event listener) is run.

Comment: Why do you use `EventEmitter.call(instance);` there? To extend with those https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/events.js#L45  properties? Why?

Comment: It works even without that.. is it some best-practice, or what?

Comment: @avasin it's similar to calling a superclass constructor. Things may work now but break in the future if you don't call it. [See also this example](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inherits_constructor_superconstructor).